# macOS english is not applied completely

Tags: macos, language

I have changed the language to English but I'm still seeing non-english message.

One of the example is when I click restart system:

It show me this:
[image]

Comment: Have you logged out/in again after changing language? (or rebooted the computer)

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the window in `System Preferences > Language & Region` ?